# Docker image expands vastly on extraction during pull, unable to pull docker image

Tags: docker

### System Information

Our company runs an application packaged in a Docker image based on arm32v7/python:3.11-bullseye image, which is around 800MB in size, on embedded Linux devices (Debian 9 OS) on-premises.

These devices ("edge devices" henceforth) have limited on-board memory; devices are standardized and have ~6GB eMMC memory each, and almost all of the space is allocated to overlayfs, which is also where Docker is configured to store it's data.

dockerd's daemon.json:

```
{
    "graph": "/overlayfs/docker",
    "dns": [
        "8.8.8.8"
    ],
    "log-driver": "json-file",
    "log-opts": {
      "max-size": "10m",
      "max-file": "3"
    }
}
```

Total image size of the application that the company uses is **839MB** after pull - I checked this via `docker image ls` on another edge device which is also working in production.

### The Problem

When pulling the image from the registry onto the edge device, I run out of space at the extraction stage - while available space is significantly larger than the image size.

Error message (actual path is different on different runs):

```
write /var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/< long hash here >/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libicudata.a: no space left on device
```

This started happening recently, with no changes to the image - the very same image was deployed on the same devices before, with little difference in available space (roughly **4GB** is available on all devices under normal conditions).

During the extraction, I have repeatedly checked available space left with `df -h`, and discovered that it consumes all ~4GB of available space before it dies.

`df -h` output before starting the pull:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        494M     0  494M   0% /dev
tpmfs           504M   48M  457M  10% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2  446M  344M   75M  83% /
/dev/mmcblk0p3  6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /overlayfs
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /var
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /etc
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /home
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /root
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /sbin
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /bin
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /usr
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /lib
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /tmp
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /mnt
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /opt
overlay         6.6G  2.5G  3.9G  39% /media
tmpfs           504M  4.0K  504M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           504M     0  504M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           101M     0  101M   0% /run/user/1001
```

`df -h` output right before pull failure:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        494M     0  494M   0% /dev
tpmfs           504M   48M  457M  10% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2  446M  344M   75M  83% /
/dev/mmcblk0p3  6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /overlayfs
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /var
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /etc
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /home
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /root
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /sbin
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /bin
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /usr
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /lib
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /tmp
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /mnt
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /opt
overlay         6.6G  6.2G  193M  98% /media
tmpfs           504M  4.0K  504M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           504M     0  504M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           101M     0  101M   0% /run/user/1001
```

This leads to the following question:

**Why does this happen** and **how do I prevent this from happening or work around this**?

So far I have tried the following:

1. Pruning docker system, and images. Result: 0B reclaimed.
2. Completely removing everything under Docker's VFS (/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/). Result: Reclaimed all space that the pull ate up, but it didn't solve the problem - upon another pull exactly the same thing happens.
3. docker save into a tar.gz archive and docker load on target device. Result: Exactly the same thing happens as when pulling.
4. Rebuild the image directly on an edge device. Same thing happens on pull of the base image.

I didn't find any way to limit the (temporary?) space Docker uses for extraction.

Comment: I'll add this as a comment because I'm not sure if it's relevant or not: When pulling, during extraction sometimes it would visibly "freeze" on a line like "4ec9c45e3a7d: Extracting  65.54kB/5.46MB" **but would actually continue writing** onto the disk. This is where the majority of consumed space comes from.

Comment: Does this image show the same behaviour on other systems (amd64, newer Debian)? What is the underlying FS type for `/overlayfs`?

Comment: Use `dive` tool to inspect the image. Alternatively, extract tar.gz and then extract each layer, and check the resulting sizes.

Comment: @AlexD The filesystem type for /overlayfs is [overlayfs](https://docs.kernel.org/filesystems/overlayfs.html). Regarding if the image shows the same behavior - you mean the failure to pull? If yes, then the behavior was not replicated - I tested it on arm64, Debian 11 device with larger computing power but still limited storage, while watching for how it grows. It never passed 1.2GB mark for the entire pull.

Comment: `overlayfs` is a union FS. I'm asking what is the underlying FS.

Comment: @AlexD Additionally, I have set up a new device identical to the production ones and loaded it with exactly the same firmware and packages, and made a pull - and I can't replicate this on a clean device. The only difference between a clean device and the production ones is the change to a logging driver I did - I added json log rotation to daemon.json.

Comment: @AlexD the upper and lower? ext4

Comment: Use `find` to create a list of all extracted files under `/var/lib/docker/` with filesizes on both systems then make `diff` between the lists.

Comment: @AlexD I guess I found the issue, but I'm not sure what to do with it. The affected systems switched to working with VFS storage driver instead of overlay2 and they refuse to come back up under overlay2 (dockerd shows the error ```failed to mount overlay: invalid argument storage-driver=overlay2``` which is typical on systems where overlayfs is not supported, which is incorrect in this case). I'm completely stumped, not sure if I need to ask a separate question for this? You might want to submit "check storage driver" as an answer, since on systems that didn't go insane 1/2

Comment: , the solution would clearly be "switch docker back to working with overlay2 storage-driver". If you have any idea what is going on here, then I'll appreciate if you'll add that too - these systems clearly have the correct kernel and have the necessary drivers (it's always the same!).

Comment: You can post your own answer here and open a new question. You may want to check this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1400)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of the problem in my case was that the Docker daemon on affected systems stopped working with overlay2 storage driver and started working with VFS storage driver. This can be identified via `docker info` or, if dockerd is down, by checking if files are present at /var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/ (or if it even exists).

VFS consumes more storage for the same images, as per [Docker documentation page on VFS storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/vfs-driver/).

Since the VFS mode was never meant to be enabled in production scenario (or, in our case, ever at all), application image was never tested with dockerd paired with that storage driver, and the resulting image under VFS indeed exceeds available space.

### The solution

In this particular scenario the solution is to manually add the following into the /etc/docker/daemon.json: `"storage-driver": "overlay2"`

Example daemon.json with just the storage driver declared:

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Unfortunately, this issue also means that it's likely overlay2 has stopped working for some reason on the target device, since it's one of the first storage drivers dockerd attempts to load, but if we assume that kernel supports overlayfs and that dockerd is not run under a container itself, correcting that is out of scope of this question.

In my particular case dockerd has likely attempted to mount its storage under /var/lib/docker or some other directory which already was mounted with OverlayFS. This is not supported in docker, so I manually have specified it to put all data in a specific folder under overlayfs/ using the **graph** option.

Here is my daemon.json that allowed dockerd to use overlay2 driver:

```
{
    "graph": "/overlayfs/docker",
    "dns": [
        "8.8.8.8"
    ]
}
```